# .ASPX pages markups are opening in web browser

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

When I double click on .aspx pages in my web application project in VS2010, instead of showing the mark up in the ide the .aspx pages are opening in the web browser as shown below. The same is happening when I run my application it opens all the .aspx pages in the web browser along the application url i.e., http://localhost123456/default.aspx. I have to close all the other pages except the http://localhost123456/default.aspx to run/ test my application.  Not sure what would cause this to happen. I am not able to find any solutions so far, any help is appreciated. I used the option View Markup (Rightclick on aspx page -> view Markup) to see the markup for now. 
[image]
**Update**
As per Mike's answer I checked the options under Open with... and I do have a Internet Explorer (Default) set as shown in the following image. Not sure how did it got there.

Deleting the Internet Explorer (Default) option might be cumbersome if I have lot of .aspx pages , if there is a way to remove this option at once for all .aspx pages rather than right clicking on each and every .aspx and remove it that would be great. 
[image]
As per @JB King suggestion I did checked the file properties and all the .aspx files are set with Opens with: Microsoft Visual Studio option as shown it the image below.
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd have to do just once as it is about the file extension to application mapping that you are changing. For example, consider how Windows knows to open a ".txt" file or ".doc" or ".pdf"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click any .aspx file in the project, select Open With...
[image: Open With example]

In the screen that pops up, select Web Form Editor, then click the Set as Default button.
[image: Open With options]

Not sure how you got Internet Explorer as an option here, but if it is there, you can just delete it.  It's not applicable for loading the aspx from disk.  Rather, to see the rendered page in IE, you'd do View in Browser or Browse With... (in which you can set your default browser, as well).

Answer (score 1):

Your address bar shows you're loading files directly from disk. This won't work. ASP.NET is not lilke static HTML. ASP.NET applications must be run from within a webserver. Install IIS and ensure ASP.NET is installed and configured, or use the Debugging Webserver (IIS Express) in Visual Studio.

Comment: I am not sure why the files are loading from disk but I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the properties of the file, there should be a line of `Opens with:` that is where you want to have `Visual Studio` rather than `Internet Explorer` as the issue is with which programs are mapped to what file extension. [Microsoft instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/change-file-open-program#1TC=windows-7) if you want those as specific steps to do.

Comment: I updated my question and added more info w.r.t to your answer.